# datetime field increases when saved

Tags: django

Good day to all. I have a problem when I save date and time in a field.

Template[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qIPm.png
  Database[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO9hw.png

This is my model:

class Mopar(models.Model):

```
    cmopar = models.AutoField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    fh0 = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Entrada')
    fh1 = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Salida')
    tminu = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Minutos')
    thora = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Horas')
    cvehi = models.ForeignKey('Vehiculos', db_column='cvehi', verbose_name='Vehiculo')
    vrcobro = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Cobro', default=0)
    vrentre = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='V. Pagado')
    vrvuelta = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Cambio')
    ctifopa = models.ForeignKey('Tifopa', db_column='ctifopa', verbose_name='Forma de Pago', default='1001')
    cesta = models.ForeignKey('Estados', db_column='cesta', verbose_name='Estado',default='10')
    ctari = models.ForeignKey('Tarifas', db_column='ctari', verbose_name='Tarifa')
    class Meta:
         db_table = 'mopar'
    def __unicode__(self):
         return str(self.vrcobro)
```

Comment: What's the problem? The time not being the same?

Comment: The null fields are the problem? In which case maybe it's the [:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] section of DateTimeField that's being read as null (Timezone, microseconds).

Comment: does not keep the same value